# How to retrieve historical events after changes to Domain Event structure

Tags: c#, cqrs, event-sourcing

Given event store with fields:

- AggregateId : integer
- Payload : blob
- Version : integer

Which contains events based on:

```
public class OrderLineAdded
{
    int Id;
    short Quantity;
}
```

... and then has further events added with an updated structure:

```
public class OrderLineAdded
{
    int ProductId; // field name has changed
    int Quantity; // field datatype has changed
}
```

When this historical data is retrieved (for analysis, etc), how do you reconstruct binary payload into meaningful data?

*Note:* the code above is not an example of a good event/event store implementation. I just want to know how this scenario should be handled.

Comment: Wouldnt you increment the version number for the second version and deserialise based on version?

Comment: @LukeMcGregor Yes, I was thinking along those lines. I want to know if there is a different/better approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rinat Abdullin outlines some domain event versioning strategies in his CQRS bliki that you might find useful to read.

https://abdullin.com/post/event-sourcing-versioning/

He suggests two possible approaches:

1. Use a serializer that can cope with renaming of properties in your event automatically such as Google's ProtoBuf Serializer.
2. Implement the following interface to manually upgrade events in-memory yourself.

```cs
public interface IUpgradeDomainEvents
{
    IEnumerable<IDomainEvent> Upgrade(IDomainEvent e, string id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only method I've seen to handle backwards compatibility is to version each change to your event. Some people create new versions in a different namespace, so that the namespace reflects the version/feature information:

```
namespace Foo.ProjectA.Release1
{
  public interface ISomeEvent {...}
}

namespace Foo.ProjectA.Release3
{
  public interface ISomeEvent {...}
}
```

Alternatively, create a new version of the class with the version/feature info in the class name:

```
namespace Foo.ProjectA
{
  public interface ISomeEvent {...}
  public interface ISomeEvent_MoreRefinedVersion {...}
}
```

Personally, I prefer the former approach, *unless* the new version adds more specific semantic meaning to the event.